# Bootstrap верстка добавление новой строки дивов

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть вот такой кусок кода.

```
 <div class="row" style="padding-top: 315px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="height: 726px;background-image:  url(image/last/little_wall.png);background-size: cover;">
                <div class="col-md-8 test">
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" >classic<br></span>
                                    <img src="image/last/first_category.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" >ellite<br></span>
                                    <img src="image/last/second_category.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" >decor<br></span>
                                    <img src="image/last/third_category.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" ><b>vintage</b><br></span>
                                    <img src="image/last/fourth_category.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" >shevron<br></span>
                                    <img src="image/last/shevron.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" >modul<br></span>
                                    <img src="image/last/modul.png">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">

                    <button  class="download_1" style="width: 260px; height: 50px; background: #889fac; margin-top: 15px;"><img src="image/arrow.png"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;">Download texturs</span></button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Не пойму как добавить новую строку дивов под `col-md-8 test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя немного неверная структура вложенности, почитай по подробнее как делать вложенные блоки на бутстрапе. Твой код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 315px;">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" style="height: 726px;background-image:  url(image/last/little_wall.png);background-size: cover;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 test">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;">
                                <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" >classic<br></span>
                                <img src="image/last/first_category.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;">
                                <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" >ellite<br></span>
                                <img src="image/last/second_category.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;">
                                <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" >decor<br></span>
                                <img src="image/last/third_category.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center;">
                                <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" ><b>vintage</b><br></span>
                                <img src="image/last/fourth_category.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                                <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" >shevron<br></span>
                                <img src="image/last/shevron.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                                <span style="text-align: center; color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;" >modul<br></span>
                                <img src="image/last/modul.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">

                <button  class="download_1" style="width: 260px; height: 50px; background: #889fac; margin-top: 15px;"><img src="image/arrow.png"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px; font-family: arial, sans-serif;">Download texturs</span></button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Тоесть если ты внутри блока хочешь вставить еще один ряд блоков, то надо их помещать внутри класса `row`

Comment: Спасибо большое, век живи - век учись.